# JavaScript get sum of next child object value in nested Array Object Tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion, nested-loops

I have an object similar to below. which has a tree structure. every parent object will have its children object. What I want to do is, Loop though every children and get the sum of the object and put it into parent object.

The top level object will have sum of all of its children, second level parent will have sum of its children and so on.

```
[
    {
        accountNo: "1",
        children: [
            {
                accountNo: "1.1",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50},
                children: [
                    {
                        accountNo: "1.1.1",
                        balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                        children: [
                            {
                                accountNo: "1.1.1.1",
                                balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                accountNo: "1.2",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        accountNo: "2",
        children: [
            {
                accountNo: "2.1",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}
            },
            {
                accountNo: "2.2",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50},
                children: [
                    {
                        accountNo: "2.2.1",
                        balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                        children: [
                            {
                                accountNo: "2.2.1.1",
                                balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired answer is as below.

```
    [
    {
        accountNo: "1",
        final: {credit: 300, debit: 300},
        children: [
            {
                accountNo: "1.1",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50},
                final: {credit: 200, debit: 250},
                children: [
                    {
                        accountNo: "1.1.1",
                        balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                        final: {credit: 100, debit: 200},
                        children: [
                            {
                                accountNo: "1.1.1.1",
                                balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                                final: {credit: 50, debit: 100}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                accountNo: "1.2",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50},
                final: {credit: 100, debit: 50}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        accountNo: "2",
        final: {credit: 150, debit: 150},
        children: [
            {
                accountNo: "2.1",
                balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}
            },
            {
                accountNo: "2.2",
                balance: null,
                final: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                children: [
                    {
                        accountNo: "2.2.1",
                        balance: null,
                        final: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                        children: [
                            {
                                accountNo: "2.2.1.1",
                                balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100},
                                final: {credit: 50, debit: 100}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there any possible way I can achive this one?
Note: Need to get the total amount from balance object, Balance object will be null sometime, in that case, need not to add anything from that object.
Example.

I tried with recursive `map` but did not work.
I tried something like below. the code is in `NodeJS`.

```
parentArray.map(async ele => {
    ele.final = { credit: 0, debit: 0 };
    getChildBalance(ele);
})

async function getChildBalance(object){
    let final = { credit: 0, debit: 0 };
    object.children.map(async child => {
        let fin = await getChildBalance(child);
        final = {
            credit: final.credit + child.balance.credit + fin.final.credit,
            debit: final.debit + child.balance.debit + fin.final.debit
        };
    })
    object.final;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use async functions here. And do you want to add the `final` properties to your existing object, or create a new copy of it with the new properties added and without modifying the original one?

Comment: Yeah, I tried without that also. but all the credit and debit values will be 0, I'm not getting child sum to the parent.

Comment: Also, your object's JSON syntax is invalid, there are some missing commas and the `accountNo` properties are not valid numbers (they are probably strings and should be in quotes).

Comment: Yeah, Just noticed that and updated that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple functional approach.  We map over the input.  For each item we recursively process the children, and then combine their `final` properties with the current one (if they all exist) into the `final` node.  We include a trivial `sum` helper function, rather than having duplicate `reduce` calls.

We don't assume that what's shown is all the fields, so we use `...rest` parameters to capture the remaining fields.  The `_` and `__` parameters are because we're inside a `map` call, which adds `index` and `array` arguments, which we want to ignore before we default our `kids` argument.  If that's too ugly, we could do this with a `call` function or with a local `kids` variable in the function body.

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const collect = (xs) => 
  xs .map (({balance, children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = collect (children)) => ({
    ...rest,
    balance,
    final: {
      credit: (balance?.credit ?? 0) + sum (kids .map (({final: {credit}}) => credit)),
      debit: (balance?.debit ?? 0) + sum (kids .map (({final: {debit}}) => debit))
    },
    ...(kids.length ? {children: kids} : {})
  }))

const input = [{accountNo: "1", children: [{accountNo: "1.1", balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}, children: [{accountNo: "1.1.1", balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}, children: [{accountNo: "1.1.1.1", balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}}]}]}, {accountNo: "1.2", balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}}]}, {accountNo: "2", children: [{accountNo: "2.1", balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}}, {accountNo: "2.2", balance: {credit: 100, debit: 50}, children: [{accountNo: "2.2.1", balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}, children: [{accountNo: "2.2.1.1", balance: {credit: 50, debit: 100}}]}]}]}]

console .log (
JSON .stringify (
  collect(input)
, null, 4)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Although I used other answer to solve the issue, I'm making this as answer since this answer explains what we are doing and fairly simple. I used other answer coz that suites my requirement and adding another helper `sum` function was not an option in my case.

Comment: Note that it's not hard to inline those calls to `sum`.  But I would not recommend doing so unless it was essential.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you want to add the final balances to your existing object:

```js
function addFinalBalance(object) {
    const final = { credit: 0, debit: 0 };
    
    if (object.balance) {
        final.credit += object.balance.credit;
        final.debit += object.balance.debit;
    }
  
    if (object.children) {
      object.children.forEach(child => {
          addFinalBalance(child);
          final.credit += child.final.credit;
          final.debit += child.final.debit;
      });
    }
    object.final = final;
}

// usage:
parentArray.forEach(addFinalBalance);
```

You can alse use this functional-style solution, that creates a new object with the final balances and leaves the existing object unmodified.

```js
function addChildBalanceImmutable(object) {
    const children = object.children ? object.children.map(addChildBalanceImmutable) : [];
  
    const final = {
        credit: (object.balance ? object.balance.credit : 0) + children.reduce((s, x) => s + x.final.credit, 0),
        debit: (object.balance ? object.balance.debit : 0) + children.reduce((s, x) => s + x.final.debit, 0)
    };
  
    return { ...object, final, children };
}

// usage
const parentArrayWithFinalBalance = parentArray.map(addFinalBalanceImmutable);
```

Comment: I will try this once. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)